# jQuery check all checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I thought this would be simple I have a table with the first column a checkbox
I am using this code to make the checkbox check all the other checkboxs

```
$('.checkall').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('tbody:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

The HTML/Jquery code to create the table

```
 $("#menuarea").html('<a href="#!/home" id="gotohome"><div id="backmain" class="backbg">Back</div></a><div id="nav" class="backbgright">New Business Lead</div>'+
                        '<div id="dowithleads"></div>'+
                        '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="sortable paginated" id="manageleads">'+
'   <thead>'+
'       <tr>'+
'           <th class="small"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkall" value="Yes"></th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Created Time</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Company</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Lead Name</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Phone No.</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha bigger">Email</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Lead Owner</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha last">Lead Status</th>'+
'       </tr>'+
'   </thead>'+
'   <tbody>'+
'       <tr>'+
'           <td class="small"><input type="checkbox" class="formbox"></td>'+
'           <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>'+
'           <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>'+
'           <td class="center">1.6</td>'+
'           <td class="center">A</td>'+
'           <td class="center bigger">A</td>'+
'           <td class="center">A</td>'+
'           <td class="center last">A</td>'+
'       </tr>'+
'       <tr>'+
'           <td class="small"><input type="checkbox" class="formbox"></td>'+
'           <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>'+
'           <td>Win 94+ / OSX.1+</td>'+
'           <td class="center">1.5</td>'+
'           <td class="center">D</td>'+
'           <td class="center bigger">A</td>'+
'           <td class="center">N</td>'+
'           <td class="center last">A</td>'+
'       </tr>'+
'</table>');
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using jQuery 1.6.x, use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('.checkall').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('table').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Also note that `$(this).parents('tbody:eq(0)')` does not select anything. Your `.checkall` is not inside a `tbody`. I changed it to `$(this).closest('table')`.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea why you're appending that huge block of html via javascript, esspecilly since there arn't any dynamically generated data.

But the reason its not working is because that `.checkall` element is not available on page load, it gets added after your tell it to bind the click event.

You can instead use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('.checkall').live('click',function () {
    $(this).parents('tbody:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

You should also close your `</tbody>`

Comment: That is just test data, the data is getting from a JSON file. thats why

Answer (score 0):

Fully working code, already had it written by the time the other two posted, so no point wasting it :)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$('.checkall').live('click', function () {
    checked = ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') ? 'true' : false;
    $(':checkbox').each(function(){ $(this).attr('checked', checked); });
});


$("#menuarea").html('<a href="#!/home" id="gotohome"><div id="backmain" class="backbg">Back</div></a><div id="nav" class="backbgright">New Business Lead</div>'+
                        '<div id="dowithleads"></div>'+
                        '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="sortable paginated" id="manageleads">'+
'   <thead>'+
'       <tr>'+
'           <th class="small"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkall" value="Yes"></th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Created Time</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Company</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Lead Name</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Phone No.</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha bigger">Email</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Lead Owner</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha last">Lead Status</th>'+
'       </tr>'+
'   </thead>'+
'   <tbody>'+
'       <tr>'+
'           <td class="small"><input type="checkbox" class="formbox"></td>'+
'           <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>'+
'           <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>'+
'           <td class="center">1.6</td>'+
'           <td class="center">A</td>'+
'           <td class="center bigger">A</td>'+
'           <td class="center">A</td>'+
'           <td class="center last">A</td>'+
'       </tr>'+
'       <tr>'+
'           <td class="small"><input type="checkbox" class="formbox"></td>'+
'           <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>'+
'           <td>Win 94+ / OSX.1+</td>'+
'           <td class="center">1.5</td>'+
'           <td class="center">D</td>'+
'           <td class="center bigger">A</td>'+
'           <td class="center">N</td>'+
'           <td class="center last">A</td>'+
'       </tr>'+
'</table>');

});
```